# Using ADO.NET SqlClient library : how to access the plain-text value of an encrypted column in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, encryption-symmetric, sqlclient

**Problem statement**

I have implemented symmetric key in my TestDb. I want to open the keys in C# code, for that I wrote the code shown here. It uses SQL Server Management object library to open key from the database.

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        
string certificateName = "CLECertificate";

ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
Server srv1 = new Server(serverConnection);

Database database = srv1.Databases[sqlConnection.Database.ToString()];

if (database.SymmetricKeys.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (SymmetricKey item in database.SymmetricKeys)
    {
        item.OpenWithCertificate(certificateName);
    }
}
```

**What I want to achieve**

I want to achieve this without a database hit if possible. Or I want to open the key with connection and keep it open even after connection is closed. so that next database select wont have to open the key first.

I used Always Encrypted in SQL Server Enterprise. It works fine when this key added in connection string

```
"Column Encryption Setting=Enabled"
```

This keyword is consumed in `System.Data.SqlClient` to open the connection.

There should be a way to do something like this for column level encryption with symmetric keys.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand this _without a database hit_. If the keys are stored in the DB then this seems practically impossible. Also _open the key with connection and keep it open even after connection is closed._ if you close the connection how is it possible to heve it still open after?

Comment: Application permissions don't meet the requirements? _Assuming your application has the required database permissions and can access the column master key, the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server will encrypt any query parameters that target encrypted columns, and will decrypt data retrieved from encrypted columns returning plaintext values of .NET types, corresponding to the SQL Server data types set for the columns in the database schema._ REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the link you shared is for Always Encrypted it works fine in that case. But I'm looking for something to _Open Symmetric Key_ using SQL Data Provider or other library

Comment: Use `DecryptByKey` as documented, assuming it was encrypted using `EncryptByKey` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data?view=sql-server-ver16